# Linux bash script that kills a process (not started by me) after x amount of time

Tags: linux, bash

I'm pretty inexperienced with Linux bash.  That being said, I have a CentOS7 machine that runs a COTS application server.  This application server runs other processes that sometimes hang.  Since I have no control over the start of these processes, I'm looking for a script that runs every 2 minutes that kills processes of the name "spicer" that have been running for longer than 10 minutes.  I've looked around and have only been able to find answers for processes that are run and owned by me.

I use the command `ps -eo pid, command,etime | grep spicer` to get all the spicer processes.  The output of this command looks like:

```
18216 spicer -l/opt/otmm-10.5/Spi       14:20
18415 spicer -l/opt/otmm-10.5/Spi       11:49
etc...
18588 grep --color=auto spicer
```

I don't know if there's a way to parse this directly in bash.  I'm also not well-versed at all in other Linux tools.  I know that awk (or gawk) could possibly help.

**EDIT**

I have no control over the data that the process is working on.

Comment: You may wish to consider using `pgrep`

Comment: If you have root privileges you can kill processes that you do not own.

Comment: @merlin2011 That's what I've been doing.  I'm tired of doing it myself.  It's a huge timesink.  This is why I would like the script to run every 2 minutes, so that I don't have to keep checking manually

Comment: @arco444 Looked into it.  Is there a way that I can see how long the process has been running using pgrep?

Comment: Make sure that the processes don't hang.

Comment: @hek2mgl I made an edit.  Making sure the processes don't hang is not something I have control over.  One could also argue that that's exactly why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Can you wrap the executable of `spicer` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about wrapping the executable of `spicer` and start it using the `timeout` command? Let's say it is installed in `/usr/bin/spicer`. Then issue:

```
cp /usr/bin/spicer{,.orig}
echo '#!/bin/bash' > /usr/bin/spicer
echo 'timeout 10m spicer.orig "$@"' >> /usr/bin/spicer
```

---

Another approach would be to create a cronjob defintion into `/etc/cron.d/kill_spicer`. Like this:

```
* * * * * root kill $(ps --no-headers -C spicer -o pid,etimes | awk '$2>=600{print $1}')
```

The cronjob will get executed minutely and uses `ps` to obtain a list of spicer processes that run longer than 10minutes and passes them to `kill`.

Probably you even want `kill -9` if the process is hanging.

Comment: I like this idea.  Will this preserve the command line arguments as well?

Comment: Yes, I've changed quoting. Now it should pass arguments properly.

Comment: just a suggestion for an edit, but you could use etimes (for seconds) instead of etime, that way you don't have to parse the time.

Comment: @sfedak Good point! Far better than parsing `MM:SS` with awk.Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for this.  I decided to go with the cron approach.  I liked the idea of wrapping it, but the cron approach offered me a bit more flexibility:  if I install a patch, I would have to redo the first approach, whereas with the cron approach, I wouldn't have to do it.

Comment: Good decision! I would go with the cron approach. Besides your argument, I also think it is cleaner.

Comment: when there's nothing to kill, I get spammed with messages into /var/spool/root/mail.  Any way that I can make this a little more robust to not run the kill command if that happens?

Comment: Quick and dirty, redirect output to /dev/null: ` ... > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-C` option of `ps` to select processes by name.

```
ps --no-headers -C spicer -o pid,etime
```

Then you can use `cut` to filter the results, if the spacing is consistent. On my system the `pid` field takes up 8 characters, so I'd use

```
kill $(ps --no-headers -C spicer -o pid,etime | cut -c-8)
```

If the spacing is inconsistent (but if so, what kind of messed up `ps` are you using? :-P), you can use `awk { print $1 }` instead of `cut`.